# how to iterate a list to create to Map?

Tags: scala

I have two functions that iterate a list and make a map out of it.

```
  def indexedShade: Map[String, Color] =
    myTextFile.map(c => (c.toShade, c)).toMap
  def indexedQuantity: Map[String, Color] =
    myTextFile.map(c => (c.toQuantity, c)).toMap
```

Since I'm iterating over `myTextFile` multiple times, I would like to just iterate once and create the two maps needed. How can I create a function that only iterates **once** and returns **two** `Map[String, Color]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really need to iterate only once and build `map`'s on fly, you can do it with `foldLeft`:

```
val (indexedShade, indexedQuantity) = myTextFile
  .foldLeft((Map.empty[String, Color], Map.empty[String, Color]))((acc, cur) => 
    (acc._1 + (cur.toShade -> cur), acc._2 + (cur.toQuantity -> cur)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with  fold

```
val (map1,map2) = myTextFile.
          foldLeft((Map[String,Color](),Map[String,Color]()))
            {case ((m1,m2),c)=>(m1 +(c.toShade->c), m2+(c.toQuantity->c))}
```